# calling std::vector::insert function in namespace or in header fails

Tags: c++11, c++14, stdvector

I am trying to insert into a vector in a header file and it is not compiling for some reason.

```
#include <vector>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
    
namespace test
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> HEADERDATA{0x65, 0x73, 0x68, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
    std::vector<uint8_t> ADDITIONALDATA{0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00};
    std::vector<uint8_t> DATA(HEADERDATA);
    DATA.insert(std::end(DATA), std::begin(ADDITIONALDATA), std::end(ADDITIONALDATA));
}

int main() {return 0;}
```

the compiler throws an error as:

```
<source>:15:1: error: 'DATA' does not name a type
   15 | DATA.insert(std::end(DATA),
```

However, if I move the insert into the main function, it works.

```
int main() 
{
    using namespace test;
    DATA.insert(std::end(DATA), std::begin(ADDITIONALDATA), std::end(ADDITIONALDATA));
}
```

Here is the link to [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/MYbfof).

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: You can only use statements inside a function. `DATA.insert(std::end(DATA), std::begin(ADDITIONALDATA), std::end(ADDITIONALDATA));` is an expression statement so at the namespace level it's out.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. -> Can you please explain the statement "is an expression statement so at the namespace level it's out" or can you point to the resources where I can read more about this? Also, if I write a statement as "const auto text = printf("hello");" in a namespace or in a header file. It works. So what is the difference here?

Comment: `const auto text = printf("hello");` is a declaration. Declarations are allowed outside of functions. Other things are not. Technically declaration-statement is a kind of statement so it is not correct to say that *all* statements are disallowed outside of functions. Expression-statements, however, are disallowed. Any C++ book should explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to write statements outside of a body of a function. Code can be run only from initializers, which is why the definition of the three variables works.

You can use an in-line lambda to create and return the collection:

```
namespace test
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> HEADERDATA{0x65, 0x73, 0x68, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
    std::vector<uint8_t> ADDITIONALDATA{0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00};
    std::vector<uint8_t> DATA([](){
        std::vector<uint8_t> data(HEADERDATA);
        data.insert(std::end(data), std::begin(ADDITIONALDATA), std::end(ADDITIONALDATA));
        return data;
    }());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, if I write a statement as "const auto text = printf("hello");" in a namespace or in a header file. It works. So what is the difference here?

Comment: @cpp_enthusiast No difference; it is a variable definition (of type `int`) initialized with the expression `printf("hello")`.

Comment: @cpp_enthusiast `const auto text = printf("hello");` is a declaration. Declarations and statements are different things. Declarations are allowed outside of functions. Statements are not.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. It makes sense. Thanks